# How to detect the edge of the the curve?

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB `edge` function to find the edge of an item in a picture. It's easy to deal with some individual item, like:

[image]

I can use `edge` function to get the boundary

[image]

However, when the picture change to

[image]

the boundary will be

[image]

It's obvious that in figure 3, there are two thick curves that are crossed. Is it possible to get the boundary for any individual one, rather than to get the boundary in figure 4?

Comment: @whuber You are right, few viewed till now. Thank you, can I directly copy and paste the question there?

Comment: I would convert your raster to vector lines, which will allow you a host of options.